# Docker on Windows and django

Tags: django, windows, docker

I have docker on Windows and ubuntu container and when I run django server there i can't see it in my browser under 127.0.0.1. I created docker container with ports exposed. When I created nginx image i could see nginx page in my browser. Why cant I see django page ? When I look at my containers I see ports 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp next to my container

Comment: Are you using docker machine or the new docker for windows? Could you also include the command you ran to start the django container?

Comment: I am using docker for Windows, command was docker run -it -p 80:80 ubuntu bash

Comment: What's the output of `docker ps` when your django container is running?

Comment: The output is fd898bf4bc70 izaya/current "bash"   2 days ago up 30 seconds 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp workspace

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not docker related since your nginx image is working. Could you enter in your container using bash and execute `wget` or `curl` on localhost ?

If you see your page (or the html) it is probably a docker problem. If not check your django configuration.

Please post your `Dockerfile` and the exact docker run command you are using.

Regards

Comment: When I used wget http://localhost:8000 it works.  I used docker run -it -p 80:80 bash. My dockerfile has only one line which is from docker/workspace:latest

Comment: My bad I am not creating my container from this file. I don't see any dockerfiles in my documents

Comment: Use docker run -it -p 80:8000 bash